# SED command matches regex but does not substitute

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I am working on building a .sed file to start scripting the setup of multiple apache servers. I am trying to get sed to match the default webmaster email addresses in the .conf file which works great with this egrep. However when I use sed to try and so a substitute search and replace i get no errors back but it also does not do any substituting. I test this by running the same egrep command again.

```
egrep -o '\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})?\b' /home/test/httpd.conf
```

returns

```
admin@your-domain.com
root@localhost
webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
```

The sed command I'm trying to use is

```
sed -i '/ServerAdmin/ s/\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})?\b/MY_ADMIN_ADDRESS@gmail.com/g' /home/test/httpd.conf
```

After running I try and verify the results by running the egrep again and it  returns the same 3 email address indicating nothing was replaced.

Comment: I had to make this an extended regular expression and it now it replaces all but one of the addresses. It misses "admin@your-domain.com"

Update: might be because its not looking for "-" in the areas after @

Comment: is your `admin@your-domain.com` following `ServerAdmin` in conf file?

Comment: nope, ive been fighting with this and forgot to even check. guess i already answered my own question then with it needing to be extended regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sed must be told that it needs to use extended regular expressions using the -r option then making the sed command as follows.

```
sed -ir '/ServerAdmin/ s/\b[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})?\b/MY_ADMIN_ADDRESS@gmail.com/g' /home/test/httpd.conf
```

Much thanks to  [Kent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164835/kent) for pointing out that the address it was missing wasnt following a `ServerName`

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume that any two tools use the same regular expression syntax.  If you're going to be doing replacements with `sed`, use `sed` to test - not `egrep`.  It's easy to use `sed` as if it were a `grep` command:  `sed -ne '/pattern/p'`.

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I've come back to read this syntax at least a half dozen times. One of these days I will remember it and it will the invaluable